# Problem with css scale transform and filter blur

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, css-filters

I have problem on Chrome browser while combining two properties: `filter: blur(15px)` and `transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1)`.

I have two images, one over another. Image on higer layer is blurred, but it's edges got transparent when I applied that filter, so I added `overflow:hidden` to parent div, and scaled up image. I expected to see just opaque part of image.

It works as expected on Firefox and Opera, however on Chrome and MS Edge browsers not. How to fix this?

[image: preview of the result]

```css
#images-box{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 280px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.image{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558389157-a986a38f3431?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
.image.blured{
  -webkit-filter: blur(14px);
  filter: blur(14px);
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1);
  transform: scale3d(1.2,1.2,1);
}
```

```html
<div id="images-box">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image blured"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome Version 74.0.3729.157. I don't see any transparent edges.

Comment: Screen was made on Chrome 75.0.3770.100. Maybe it's a browser bug.

Comment: Works as expected for me in Version 74.0.3729.169 OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `scale3d(1.2,1.2,1)` to `scale(1.2)` helped me on Chrome 86.0.4240.198.